# Multiple A7RII syncronized using Sony Camera Remote API

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I am looking to synchronize 6 SONY A7RII cameras such that I can take photos with all of them at very close to the same time (<250mS latency). Can I call the Remote API if I connected all 6 cameras to the same WiFi router? I'm developing Android application. Is it even possible to develop such solution at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can only connect 1 camera to a phone at a time, the API is not supported over a router or to multiple cameras unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Should work (haven't tried myself) over PTP/IP. See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797733/5374125).