# Get files from multiple Sony A7RII Cameras with the Sony Camera Remote API

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

I would like to download images from 20 Sony A7RII cameras, to a computer, without having to get the memory cards from the 20 cameras. I do not need to synchronize the triggering, I know this is not possible via software. I do not need the discovery service, I can figure the ip addresses myself.

I need to be able to read the image list and download images. Even better would be to get a notification when new images are available. Is the Sony SDK limited to a single camera? Is there really only an HTTP pull API via WIFI, or is there any way to connect to these cameras, via USB for example.

This is very easy to do with the Canon SDK, I'm looking for a similar solution for Sony alpha cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Camera Remote API you can read the image list and download images, however since the API uses a direct WiFi connection it can only connect to 1 camera at a time.  The API only works over WiFi, not USB unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect all 20 cameras to one wifi-AP and then use PTP/IP to connect to all cameras at the same time.

- PTP/IP supports event messages on new pictures being available but not sure if Sony supports it
- Alternatively, you could leave the connections open and do regular pulls to check for new files
- PTP also supports initiating captures (although I haven't tried on the A7RII) but you would have to ensure synchronisation yourself

If you're using Java, you could use my [PTP/IP implementation](https://github.com/Fimagena/libptp) which is explicitly tested with the Sony A7.

(Disclaimer: I have tried this only with the A7 but am assuming that the A7RII supports the same protocol.)